# Установка расширения не из магазина в Chrome без действий пользователя

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, reverse-engineering

Хочу написать прогу, которая ставит расширение в фоновом режиме.

До чего я дошел: хром при установке расширения трогает только два файла: `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` и `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Secure Preferences`.

Пути в JSON-файле буду приводить следующим образом: ключ1.ключ2 и тп.

Он делает следующее: добавляет информацию в `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Secure Preferences` по пути extensions.settings., так же в `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences` по пути extensions.toolbar(добавляет в массив ID), так же в extensions.install_signature.ids(аналогично). Но! При этом по пути protection.macs.<глобальные ключи, к примеру extensions.settings.> лежит строчка с хешом данных, представленных выше, хеш - это HMAC SHA256 от (device_id + path(это тот самый путь к ключу, к примеру extensions.settings.) + value(stringifyed-json от объекта, который лежит по пути который хешируем) без пустых объектов внутри. Так же от protection.macs считаешься хеш и записывается в protection.super_mac. Вопрос в том, где хром берет ключ для HMAC'а - уже день роюсь в сорсах хрома не могу понять.

И еще вопрос - как получать ID раширения?

Comment: Саша Новожилов - а как с тобой связаться? Что то нету тут кнопки написать в личку (( Сейчас делаю продукт и в installer нужно сделать чтоб расширения ставилось из файла а не магазина. На 2023 это еще работает ? :) А то мое расширения edge пропускает, а гугл отклоняет говорит конфликт интересов

Comment: @AdamTraffic напиши в тг mrlolthe1st

Answer (score 1):

Если еще актуально, то здесь все расписано https://www.adlice.com/google-chrome-secure-preferences/, в частности про seed для hmac:

The seed is unique to a machine where Chrome is installed (or per Chrome version?). It’s stored in Chrome’s installation path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\ChromeVersion\resources.pak). This format is quite known now, and well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633357/how-to-unpack-resources-pak-from-google-chrome. All you need to do is to look for the first resource with a length of 64.